# interchangeable operation of two electric motors without PLC

Tags: relay, control, control-system, solid-state-relay, plc

I have two motors that drive an air compressor. I have a pressure switch to turn the motors on/off.

The sequence I want is:

- when pressure switch turns ON - motor 1 starts,
- when pressure switch turns OFF .. motor 1 stops,
- when pressure switch turns ON again .. motor 2 starts,
- and so on.

The idea was to use something called pulse relay (a relay that changes contact position with each pulse) and used an on-delay-timer to create a 1 second pulse when pressure switch turns ON.

The problem here is that I can't find this pulse relay and not sure if it exists (my friend told me about it). Is there any alternative method for doing this circuit or do you know a relay model that serves this purpose or any other suggestion could help me with that?

Thank you!

Comment: You are describing a Lead / Lag control scheme. This can be accomplished with a flip / flop and a few other components (control voltage) and two contactors (motor voltage). There are lots of sources on the internet both for turn key solutions and schematics if you want to build your own.

Comment: Thanks Tyler .. I will search for flip flop and come back if I have additional questions

Comment: Motor alternation is often used for sewage lift pumps. Search "pump alternation" or "motor alternation" and "lead/lag" to find information.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done entirely with two relays (one @ 24 Vdc, the other at the contactor coil voltage), a capacitor, a small transistor, a couple of resistors.  You will also need a tiny auxiliary 24Vdc power supply for the latch relay.

One relay closes every time the pressure switch closes and is used to set or reset the second relay.

The other relay functions as a latch and steers the pressure switch signal to one  motor or the other.

I'm working from ancient memory but I'm sure that the component values shown should work quite well.

C1 and K2 function as a Master/Slave flip-flop.  When the circuit first powers up, both relays are relaxed and C1 is discharged.

When the pressure switch closes, K1 closes.  K2's normally-closed contact routes the pressure switch signal to motor #1 contactor and C1 charges to 24V.

Nothing else happens until the pressure switch opens.  The motor contactor is released and C1 now applies 24V to the base of Q1.  K2 closes but nothing else happens because the pressure switch is open.

When the pressure switch closes again, K2's normally-open contact routes the pressure switch signal to motor #2 contactor and C1 discharges to zero.

When the pressure switch opens again, the motor contactor is released and C2 now pulls the base of Q1 towards ground.  K2 opens but nothing else happens because the pressure switch is open.

The above cycle repeats forever.

The time constant of C1 and R1 is chosen to ensure that K2 turns OFF reliably.  The values shown give a time constant of about 100ms, which should be sufficient.  Increase the value if C1 if needed.

R2 ensures that the capacitor charge / discharge current doesn't erode the relay contacts.  R3 isn't really needed because Q1 functions as an emitter-follower.

Notice that K2 doesn't change state until just after the pressure switch opens.  This eliminates contactor chatter and contact erosion.

---

The 24 Vdc power supply can be eliminated if you choose a 110 Vdc relay for K2.  You would have to also use high voltage components for C1 & Q1 but the value of C1 can decrease in direct proportion to the voltage increase (increase R1 by the same proportion).  This is, of course, assuming that your control voltage / motor contactor coil voltage is 120 Vac (North America).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFlZpY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Before you do, (1) it's probably an AC system so charging capacitors will require an additional DC supply and (2) using capacitors to delay relay drop out has the problem of slow contact opening. On a motor circuit that will cause a lot of contact wear due to sparking.

Comment: Thanks for your great replies , I've come to a practical solution of my problem .. I used latching relay Hager EPN515 and it does it all

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9ACgv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Two-relay flip-flop with DPDT relay repeat of pressure switch.*

Setup: On power-on with empty reservoir PS (pressure switch) is closed. PS will open when set pressure is reached.

- Initial conditions all relays off.
- Power is applied, PS is closed so R3 pulls in. R2 pulls in through R1b. Motor 2 is now powered through PS and R2c NO (normally open) contact.
- Pressure rises and PS opens. R3 drops out. R2b is closed and this holds R2 energised. Meanwhile R1 picks up through R2a. Both R1 and R2 are now on. Motors are off.

After some time pressure falls again ...

- PS closes again pulling in R3. R1 remains pulled in through R1a but R2 drops out as R1b is open. Motor 1 is now powered through PS and R2c NC (normally closed) contact.
- Pressure rises and PS opens again. R3 drops out. Since R2 is de-energised both R1 and R2 are unlatched and drop out. Motors are off.

We are now back at the initial conditions. The pattern will repeat on next PS closure.

Note that snubbers will be required. The circuit is a little harsh on the relays and motors in that on closure of PS one motor fires briefly before R2c changes over. I will leave it as an exercise to the reader to determine if using R1c would avoid this problem.

Comment: Thanks for your great replies , I've come to a practical solution of my problem .. I used latching relay Hager EPN515 and it does it all

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for your great replies , I've come to a practical solution of my problem .. I used latching relay Hager EPN515 and it does it all

Comment: Would you care to sketch a schematic of how you used this to solve your problem? It may help someone else in future.

Comment: Sure , I will do it